# Multiple overlapping ListAnimations

Tags: listanimate

I have two separate `ListAnimate`s that should appear in the same graphics area.  Here's a minimal working example:

```
myanim1 = Table[
  Graphics[{Point[{0, 0}], Red, PointSize[0.05], Point[{a, 0}]},
   PlotRange -> {{-.1, 1}, {-.1, 1}}],
  {a, 0, 1, .05}];

myanim2 = Table[
  Graphics[{Point[{0, 0}], Blue, PointSize[0.05], Point[{0, b}]},
   PlotRange -> {{-.1, 1}, {-.1, 1}}],
  {b, 0, 1, .05}];
```

I can easily execute *either* one by

`ListAnimate[myanim1]` or `ListAnimate[myanim2]`

I would like, however, to make a single `ListAnimation` environment with *two* progress bars, once for each animation and each animation shows in the same plot area.  Thus when I click on the right-triangle to play one of the animations, it does so.  When I click on the right-triangle to play the other of the animations it does so *BUT with the first animation visible in its current state*.

For example, I can stop one animation with the red dot halfway through its course and then animate the blue dots.

And so forth.

I've tried `ListAnimate[myanim1,myanim2]`, `ListAnimate[{myanim1,myanim2}]`, `Show[ListAnimate[myanim1],ListAnimate[myanim2]]`, `Show[{ListAnimate[myanim1],ListAnimate[myanim2]}]`, and so forth, all without success.

I realize I can achieve what I seek in a somewhat kludgy way, with `Manipulate` with two sliders, one for each animation.

But is there a way to use `ListAnimate` proper in this task?

Comment: `Manipulate[
 Join[myanim1, myanim2][[i + j-1]], {i, 1, Length@myanim1, 1}, {j, 
  1, Length@myanim2, 1}]`

Comment: Yes... `Manipulate` works... thanks.  But I guess there's no provision for a "multiple" ListAnimate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As is, `ListAnimate` allows only a single frame list with a single `Animator` control.

[`ListAnimate > Details and Options:`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListAnimate.html)  ***"ListAnimate generates a Manipulate object containing an Animator"***

as can be seen by inspecting the `FullForm` or `Head`:

```
Head @ ListAnimate[Table[Plot[Sin[n x], {x, 0, 10}], {n, 5}]]
```

> ```
> Manipulate
> ```

Thus, any enhancement of `ListAnimate` to allow multiple frame lists has to use `Manipulate` (or `DynamicModule`). However, this is straightforward enough:

```
ClearAll[multipleListAnimate, animatorControl]

animatorControl = {{#, 1, #2}, 1, #3, 1,
   ControlType -> Animator, 
   AppearanceElements -> {"ProgressSlider", FasterSlowerButtons", 
      "ResetButton", "PlayPauseButton", "DirectionButton", 
      "StepLeftButton", "StepRightButton"}, 
   AnimationRunning -> False} &;


multiListAnimate[frames : {__}, labels : {__}, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 With[{vl = Symbol["$$$x" <> ToString @ #] & /@ Range[Length @ frames]}, 
  Manipulate[Show @ MapThread[Take] @ {frames, List /@ vl}, 
   Evaluate[Sequence @@ (MapThread[animatorControl] @
       {vl, PadRight[labels, Length[frames], ""], Length /@ frames})], 
   opts, AppearanceElements -> None]]
```

***Example:***

```
multiListAnimate[{myanim1, myanim2}, {"myanim1", "myanim2"}]
```

[image]

Replace the labels `{"myanim1", "myanim2"}` with `Graphics[{#, Disk[{0, 0}, Offset[5]]}, ImageSize -> 15] & /@ {Blue, Red}` to get

[image]

Comment: We can replace `Manipulate` with `Animate` to get the same result.

Comment: Who else could answer this but the undisputed master... 363k reputation *indeed*!  Thanks so much.  ($+1, \checkmark$). Perhaps WRI will introduce some version of multiListAnimate in the future.